# How can I make my curves settings permanent?

Tags: edit-mode

- How can I change Blender settings inside the installation directory to where when I create a curve, It will automatically be on *Resolution* of 32 *Depth* of 3 and *Fill* *Full Mode* ?
- Also is there away when I Import files in Blender to have them automatically locked to position to where i cant move them on accident?

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: I don't think there's any built in way to achieve the first one, though I suspect it would be relatively trivial to achieve with some python scripting.